# How do I set `OutputPath` in a Visual Studio 2017 project (new .csproj file format) without the target framework cluttering the resolved path?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Setting `OutputPath` in the new Visual Studio 2017 project format automatically adds the target framework in the path. For example, if I have these set in the project file:

```
<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
<OutputPath>/build/debug/<OutputPath>
```

The actual output folder will resolve to `/build/debug/net462/`, not `/build/debug/` like in the older versions.
How do I solve this without workarounds like moving things around with post build actions?

Comment: I surely hope that there's no heuristic trying to decide what I'd like to get. But in my case it's just plain old .net 4.6.2 as the targetframework states in my example. edit: this is an answer to a question that I don't see anymore.

Comment: Not sure if it help but maybe try to override output settings like this:
`<PropertyGroup  Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'>
    <BaseOutputPath>/build/debug/</BaseOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)/</OutputPath>`

Comment: `BaseOutputPath` sets the outputpath base for different configurations, so it does not help in this case (I tested this to make sure). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: The first `/` in `<OutputPath>/build/debug/<OutputPath>` makes it an absolute path (in Ubuntu at least).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The solution is to use `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233608-stopping-msbuild-appending-targetframework-to-outputpath/

```
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
```

Comment: to remove the runtime identifier:
`<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>`
`<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>`

Comment: Leave it to Microsoft to (1) not give "new .csproj format" a name, (2) have VS IDE create code that doesn't work, and (3) not document the real solution. Too bad, because the solution itself is a good one.

Comment: Nowadays there is a note mentioning both these configuration parameters in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 43):

The answer above is right, but you may also want to remove the runtime identifier:

```
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
```