# How to avoid Visual Studio outputs assemblies in Target Framework Name directories?

Tags: visual-studio, build, .net-5, .net-standard, .net-6.0

We have some netstandard2.0 assemblies. When compiling they are generated within the directory `.\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0` (netstandard2.0 dir name is the [TFN the Target Framework Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)). However only `.\bin\Debug` is specified in Project Properties. And we'd like to generate those assemblies within `.\bin\Debug` to get all our assemblies with the same directory.

We developed a Post-Build event to copy back our assemblies and their json/pdb files within `.\bin\Debug` and then delete the dir `.\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0`. However this is not a good solution because the `FastUpToDate` tool used during incremental compilation does'nt find `.\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ProjectName.pdb` and thus our netstandard2.0 projects are always rebuilt even when they are up-to-date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set \`OutputPath\` in a Visual Studio 2017 project (new .csproj file format) without the target framework cluttering the resolved path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602782/how-do-i-set-outputpath-in-a-visual-studio-2017-project-new-csproj-file-form)

Comment: Yup, I couldn't find it despite googling hard for it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` to false in your projects.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Awesome, googled for it for a long time but never found it, thanks :-))